# Using Pcap.Net with thread throws 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception, pcap.net

I have this method:

```
public void rc()
{
    try{
        using (PacketCommunicator communicator = device1.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000))
        {
            richTextBox1.AppendText("Listening on " + device1.Description + "... \r\n");

            // start the capture
            communicator.ReceivePackets(0, PacketHandler);
            communicator.Break();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and when I start the programm, and call this method via

```
Thread oThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(r.rc));
        oThread.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1);
        oThread.Join();
```

it throws this at the end of line with "using (PacketCommunicator...."

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ...
>
> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Addition info: When I don't have method "rc" and thread, and the code was in constructor, I didn't have this issue with this line .

Comment: I can't see any problem in your code, but I would highly recommend you to work with `SharpPcap`. It is a widely known and a good library: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12458/SharpPcap-A-Packet-Capture-Framework-for-NET

Comment: Can you catch the exception when it is thrown to see what variable is null? Maybe 'r' or 'r.rc' are null?

Comment: THX guys but it is solved. :)